# Rails Upgrade: server says a route doesn't exist when it does!

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-3-upgrade

**Given:**

The following partial:

```
<%= form_for @user_session, :url => user_session_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <span class="field-group">
    <div>
      <%= f.label :login, "Login Name:" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :login %><br />
    </div>
  </span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <span class="field-group">
    <div>
      <%= f.label :password, "Password:" %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %> <span class="hint">Reminder: Your password is case sensitive.</span><br />
    </div>
  </span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <span class="field-group">
    <div>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  </span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <%= f.submit "Login" %>
<% end %>
```

And the following route:

```
$ rake routes | grep user_session | grep show
user_session GET /user_session/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_session"}
```

And the following route configuration:

```
# user session stuff
resources :user_session do
  member do
    put :forgot_password
    put :terms
    get :terms
  end
end  
match '/login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => 'login'
match '/logout', :to => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
```

**Problem:**

When I call the page that uses this partial, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in User_sessions#new

Showing /app/views/edit_shared/_login.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_session"}
```

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1: 
2:     <%= form_for @user_session, :url => user_session_path do |f| %>
3:       <%= f.error_messages %>
4:       <span class="field-group">
5:         <div>
```

So that route exists, but rails says it doesn't. So what gives? It was fine until I started upgrading to Rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your route only accepts `GET` requests. A form sends a `POST` request by default.

**Edit:**
First you should use your named route instead of `user_session_path`:

```
<%= form_for @user_session, :url => login_path do |f| %>
```

And the action you want is `create`, not `new` (which displays the form):

```
match '/login', :to => 'user_sessions#create', :as => 'login'
```

Comment: ël, see my edit. I added my `user_session` routing information. I thought using `resources :user_session do ... end` was enough to get what I needed for routing. What should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `:url => user_session_path` from your form. By specifying `form_for @user_session`, Rails will look up the `user_session` RESTful routes and generate the URL for you.

Answer (score 0):

changing `:url => user_session_path` to `:url => {:action => :create}` did the trick.

Comment: But then the URL is probably not "/login". Maybe this part was not important. In this case I suggest you apply Brandon's answer.